# Create (static) handle array from multiple dynamic functions

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I have the following problem:

A function expects an input parameter of an array of function-handles

```matlab
handleArray = @( param ) [ ...
    @calcSumOfParam ; ... % and so on..
    @calcSumOfParam ];

solution = calculateFunc( handleArray );
```

However, `calcSumOfParam()` actually needs more/additional input parameters (not only `param`) and is kind of heavy-structured (only an example here)

```matlab
function [ sumOfParam ] = calcSumOfParam( param , maxIter , startIter )

sumOfParam = 0;

for iter = startIter : maxIter
    sumOfParam = sumOfParam + param( iter );
end

end
```

Is there a way to do this?

I cannot use anonymous functions as I need to use loops and conditions. Also multiple functions won't work either, as I do not know the size of the `handleArray` and so the amount of functions (get it through user input).

Comment: Does example 3 in http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html help?

Comment: As I used Matlab the first time yesterday, I 'm not able to say it for sure, but this looks promising! Thank you, I give it a try and let you know!